# Can I have Composer or something else download a Git repo as a dependency of my contrib module?

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I'm working on a module and there is a sub module for scanning barcodes that requires [this](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/), quagga.
Currently you have to manually download the library and put it into the libraries dir. If I add this as a dependency to the module you cannot install it without doing this first.

Can I have composer or something download a git repo to the libraries when installing the submodule?

Edit:
libraries.yml

```
form:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    layout:
      css/commerce_pos_barcode_scanning.css: {}
  js:
    js/commerce_pos_barcode_scanning.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - commerce_pos/quagga
quagga:
  remote: https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS.git
  version: 1.0.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/blob/master/LICENSE
    gpl-compatible: yes
  js:
    /libraries/webrtc/adapter-latest.js: {}
    /libraries/quagga/quagga.min.js: {}
```

install.yml

```
function commerce_pos_barcode_scanning_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];
  if ($phase == 'install' || $phase == 'runtime') {
    $path = 'libraries/quagga/quagga.min.js';
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
      $requirements['commerce_pos_barcode_scanning'] = [
        'title' => t('POS Barcode Scanning'),
        'description' => t('To scan barcodes, you need to install the quagga JavaScript library. <a href="/modules/contrib/commerce_pos/modules/barcode_scanning/README.md">How To</a>'),
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_WARNING,
      ];
    }
    else {
      $requirements['commerce_pos_barcode_scanning'] = [
        'title' => t('POS Barcode Scanning'),
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_OK,
        'value' => t('quagga JavaScript library has been configured.'),
      ];
    }
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

Comment: It's a JS lib hosted on GitHub OK. So you can either go for a [*.libraries.yml](https://www.drupal.org/node/2947530) pulling that in automatically or use [hook_requirements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x) to declare this dep explicitly though this will not prevent your library from being installable if the requirement isn't met. It just creates a warning or error message on the status page.

Comment: But maybe you can it get it to work somehow with a [composer.json](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-composerjson-file) in your module. Though I'm not sure about how this works for (JS) libs not packaged for Composer usage.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for the response. The submodule has a libraries and install already. These do not download the library, just warn that we need it. I'll add them to the Q.

Comment: This is outside the scope of composer, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md

Comment: Just as a side note: Quagga is available on [asset-packagist.org](https://asset-packagist.org/package/search?query=quagga&platform=bower%2Cnpm) (but this still is a foreign repo that has to be added to the root project)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file `composer.js`

find `"web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],` change to

```
"web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset",
                "vendor:npm-asset",
                "vendor:bower-asset",

            ],
```

add repositories

```
{
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "serratus/quaggaJS",
                "version": "0.12.1",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/zipball/master/serratus-quaggaJS-v0.12.1-14-g862df88.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "composer/installers": "^1.0.20"
                }
            }
        }
```

and run `composer require "serratus/quaggaJS"`

Comment: OP is asking how to manage dependencies for a (contrib) module.

Comment: ley is right here I believe. I understand how composer works for a project, but not for a module honestly.

Comment: While not the answer to the question, this IMHO is the way better solution than leymannx's anwer. Manually create the composer entry. Don't mix composer-managed and self-downloaded shared libs. What happens when another module wants the same lib with conflicting version requirements?

Comment: @Hudri – This version argument doesn't count when you define a proper library with a proper version. The question is just how this library could be downloaded automatically.

Comment: I was hopefully going to make it so that this library would auto install when enabling this sub-module, correct. This would go in the project's composer rather than the modules correct? Not what I want sadly

Answer (score 0):

To have this be done automatically people will simply configure their project's `composer.json` themselves. So I'd recommend to just explain one more time how this is supposed to be done via Composer on your project's page on drupal.org or in the documentation to your module.

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/43121292/2199525
- [How to use Composer to install third party libraries](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/269964/15055)
- [How to require a JS library in a composer.json file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/260754/15055)

---

Another inadvisable approach would be to provided a Drush command to download the library. Like [Semantic UI API](https://www.drupal.org/project/semantic_ui_api) does it. Browse their code on [GitLab](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/semantic_ui_api/blob/7.x-1.x/drush/semantic_ui_api.drush.inc). The command has not been ported to D8 yet. But I think you'll get the idea. Probably worth looking at their [8.x-1.x](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/semantic_ui_api/blob/8.x-1.x/semantic_ui_api.module) branch as well. And see how they solved it in D8.

Below code is from 7.x-1.x. `SEMANTIC_UI_DOWNLOAD_URL` leads to a Zip file on [GitHub](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/archive/master.zip).

> ```
>   $args = func_get_args();
>   if ($args[0]) {
>     $path = $args[0];
>   }
>   else {
>     //we have dependencies on libraries module so no need to check for that
>     //TODO: any way to get path for libraries directory?
>     //Just in case if it is site specific? e.g. sites/domain.com/libraries ?
>     $path = drush_get_context('DRUSH_DRUPAL_ROOT') . '/sites/all/libraries/semantic_ui';
>   }
>   // Create the path if it does not exist yet. Added substr check for preventing 
>   // any wrong attempts or hacks !
>   if (substr($path, -11) == 'semantic_ui' && !is_dir($path)) {
>     drush_mkdir($path);
>   }
>   if (is_dir($path . '/dist')) {
>     drush_log(dt('Semantic Ui already present at @path. No download required.', array('@path' => $path)), 'ok');
>   }
>   elseif (drush_op('chdir', $path) &&
>       drush_shell_exec('wget ' . SEMANTIC_UI_DOWNLOAD_URL . '  -O semantic_ui.zip') &&
>       drush_shell_exec('unzip semantic_ui.zip') &&
>       drush_shell_exec('rm -rf semantic_ui.zip') &&
>       drush_shell_exec('mv Semantic-UI-master/dist/* .') &&
>       drush_shell_exec('rm -rf Semantic-UI-master')) {
>     drush_log(dt('The latest Semantic Ui library has been downloaded to @path', array('@path' => $path)), 'success');
>   }
>   else {
>     drush_log(dt('Drush was unable to download the Semantic Ui library to @path', array('@path' => $path)), 'error');
>   }
> ```

Comment: IMHO a bad idea. What happens when another module wants the same lib with conflicting version requirements? This approach kind of contradicts using composer at all.

Comment: @Hudri – Of course you also register it as a proper library. Do you know any other way to auto-download a third-party lib not packaged for Composer from a contrib module?

Comment: I don't know any solution, and [composer doesn't even want to this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md)

Comment: Yes, this is a solution and it does answer the OP's question. I just think it is a problematic advice to bypass a composer limitation this way, that's why I've given a -1. You don't need to download it manually, but you have to manually add the foreign repo to the root project.

Comment: Or don't put the lib in a shared, composer-managed folder, then this is fine too.

Comment: @Hudri – Got it. OP should simply explain in the docs how this is supposed to be done via the project's `composer.json`. Totally agree. Updated answer.